# How can I use a pre-push git hook to check whether certain files or directories different between the local and the remote branch?

Tags: git, github, hook, githooks

... and more specifically, why can't I programmatically fetch a file?

I am new to writing git hooks.  I want to be able to perform action X if a configuration file is changed since the last push. I have thought of two approaches:

1) get the relevant file from github and run diff.

2) scan the commit history since the last push for the presence of the file, using the information you get for free in a pre-push git hook (looks like this when I log it):

```
Name of the remote to which the push is being done: origin
URL to which the push is being done: git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>.git
local ref: refs/heads/<mybranch>
local sha1: c83288a9e0b2a5c9f7b1940360e052b2d4468222
remote ref: refs/heads/<mybranch>
remote sha1: 164c55a9af0abee06bc03e91e162301ebf2bb097
```

Right now I'm trying (1) because it feels more obvious to me. I'm not sure how to use that information to inspect all the commits for changes to the relevant file. But I'm stuck because
`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<repo-owner>/<repo>/docs-and-config/config/config.yml`as well as trying a GET command in Postman both return 404s -- I would understand not authorized, but I get not found.  If I visit the same url in my browser, I can reach it (and GitHub attaches some kind of token to it).

So I have two questions:

(1) why is this happening and can you tell me how I can fetch the remote file?
(2) do you have better ideas for how I can approach this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `pre-push` hook runs, your data hasn't been pushed to the remote system yet.  So trying to fetch the data you haven't pushed from GitHub, which doesn't have it, won't work.  GitHub gives you a 404 because it's not there yet.

Approach 2, which checks the commit history, is going to be the best approach here.  You could try something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read lref loid rref roid
do
    if echo $roid | grep -qsE '^0+$'
    then
        # Do whatever you want with a new branch.
    elif echo $loid | grep -qsE '^0+$'
    then
        # Do whatever you want with a deleted branch.
    elif git diff --name-only $loid $roid | grep -qsF "MY-FILENAME-HERE"
    then
        # Do whatever you want to do if MY-FILENAME-HERE is present in the diff.
    else
        # Do whatever you want if the file is absent.
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hm, you're right that it could be a problem if the branch were new, but it's not; the file is there -- I can see it in the browser.  So that doesn't explain my 404.  But thanks for this line `git diff --name-only "$loid..$roid" | grep -qsF "MY-FILENAME-HERE"`.  That's going to run diff on the local and remote versions of the branch, report only names of the differing files, and search for the presence of my names of interest?  I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I've updated the example to not use the range notation, which should make it more resilient to a wide variety of circumstances.